# Using HTML5 Drag and Drop for list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML:

```
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Registration</a>
            <ul ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
               <li><a href='1'>Register for Classes</a></li>
               <li><a href='2'>Retake a Course (Academic Forgiveness)</a></li>
               <li><a href='3'>View Your Holds</a></li>
```

and so on. It's a menu that displays some links. I also have another menu that should allow the user to drop "favorite links" into it:

```
 <div id="myFavorites" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>My Favorites</a>
             <ul id="favoritesList">
                <li><a href='#'>Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Test3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Test4</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

My javascript appears to be correct:

```
function drop(ev) {
    //alert("Got here");
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    //var html = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");

    document.getElementById('favoritesList').appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
//$("#favoritesList").append(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

However, when I drag the top menu to the bottom, it doesn't append the entire "li" element to the favorites, only the  element inside of it. I've also tried adding the ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" to each individual "li" element, but it's producing the same results. Any suggestions?

Comment: none of the list items have IDs, so the line with `document.getElementById(data)` doesn't make sense...

Comment: Sorry, they do in the html markup. The platform I'm running the application on generates random id's if none are present. I figured out that the problem is that the href covers the entire "li" element, so when I try to drag the li, I'm getting the href instead. Any suggestions on fixing this would be great. I'm thinking I'll just have to manually append the html I want when the drop event happens.